# Eclipse Mars won't start after installing plugin

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

I recently tried to update Eclipse Luna to Mars via the Eclipse-internal updates. However, this somehow corrupted the `Eclipse.app` file, which caused this *extremely specific and detailed* message when opening it:

[image: Error screenshot]

Because I was unable to find any direct help, I simply downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse Mars, and everything worked fine (except for the fact that I had to re-install all plugins).

Today I tried to install a plugin called `Eclipse Optimizer`, and after manually restarting eclipse, the error appeared again. This time I checked both the Apple Error Console and the `Eclipse.app` file itself, which revealed that there is nothing but the file `Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` inside.

[image: Console log]

I am running on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 and Eclipse Mars 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Macs you can't upgrade from Eclipse Luna to Mars because the application layout has been changed.

Download a complete Eclipse Mars installation and install from scratch.

Comment: I did that, and after installing a plugin it didn't work again.

Comment: It may well be that this 'Eclipse Optimizer' doesn't understand the new app layout

Comment: Why is it on the front page of the Eclipse Marketplace then?